# Changing frame won't resize UIImageView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

In my iPhone app I'm trying to programmatically resize and move a UIImageView in order to give it as origin the top-left corner of the iPhone screen and to have it to be both wide and tall as the height of the screen.
To do so I'm using with the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     //Getting screen size
     CGRect screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];

     //Creating the new frame for the UIImageView
     CGRect arect = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.size.height, screenSize.size.height);
     //Setting the image to show

     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Adele.jpg"];
     self.imageView.image = image;

     //Setting new frame and contentmode
     self.imageView.frame = arect;
     self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
}
```

self.imageView is an outlet I created with InterfaceBuilder.

Problem is that this code does not seem to have any effect on the frame of the UIImageView when I start the application. The imageview infact will be shown in the same position and with the same size that I set when I created it with IB.

Does anyone of you guys have an idea on why this code isn't working? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might need a different content mode.

Give `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` a try. In context:

```
self.imageView.frame = arect;  
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

If that doesn't work you can `initWithFrame`:

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 109.0f);
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
```

[source](http://www.iphoneexamples.com/)

Comment: The `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` didn't work although `initWithFrame` did!

Anyways isn't it a strange behavior? I mean shouldn't changing the frame of a already existing `UIImageView` instance work?